# How to fix the screen hanging at a black screen instead of booting Xubuntu?

Tags: boot, xubuntu

The problem point is pretty clear. After the initial boot stuff is over and it's time to actually boot the OS, it just hangs at a black screen with a small rectangular cursor at the top-left"ish" corner.

I can't even go to BIOS setup/options or other stuff like that, which makes me question weather this question is even on-topic. I don't know.

Does the OS have to load in order to go to BIOS options? Probably not, so that's worrying(both for my laptop and this question). This problem should occur, only when the OS couldn't boot and is stuck in recursive limbo. But here, not even BIOS options starts up...

> System info:

> OS: Xubuntu 20.4

> Manufacturer: Dell

> CPU: Intel Celeron(no idea what it exactly is; for obvious reasons)

> Graphics card: Integrated into the CPU

Note: My laptop doesn't have a battery and neeps to be operator with the charger plugged on. This is a big one.

It's not dual boot, so I can't know if any other OS would boot or not.

UPDATE: The cursor had disappeared while I was typing.

UPDATE2: The laptop has now turned off. I did try pressing some keys before that. `Fn` + `F7` and similar stuff. I did it as I read that it could be brightness stuff. But I don't think it caused the turning off as I had done it a while back with and this was the second try. And, it's not tuning back on. Ah. Maybe it will, if I pull the plug but I won't until it's the last resort.

UPDATE3: Yep, I pulled the plug and it's the same problem.

UPDATE4: I have successfully opened the boot thing(look I can't check the names). The thing that lets you choose what to boot. I hit enter with ubuntu selected but it's hanged. No progress.

Comment: I don't understand your problem - but if you can't get into your bios, it seems to be a hardware problem, since no linux distro messes with your bios settings.

Comment: @kanehekili I'm stuck in a very weird issue. That is my other account, which I created to ask this question(because my laptop... and I forgot my password). But then I forgot the password of this account, so I can probably not merge them. I will probably untangle this mess by recovering my accounts(the recovery emails of my accounts are very tangled). It might take a while, till then, Ah. Weird. I left it running for a long time and it booted up. So, yeah, my laptop is the same except the booting is very long. I think it's not the OS taking time but the hardware.

Comment: @kanehekili This is so weird. I suddenly boot up one day and my hardware can't boot up the OS as fast for some reason. I know it's the hardware as going to the BIOS settings takes longer as well. What just happened?